# how to show/hide on the same component in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm newbie in React, and I try to hide an image after I click the same image and then show the dropdown component from other folder. How do I do that?

I'm current stuck in not being able to hide the same picture and it shows the same picture at different spot.

Or is there better way to do it?

Below is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import mind_zebra from '../../images/MindScribe-zebra.png';
import dropdown from '../DropDown/DropDown.js';
import './entry.css';

class Entry extends React.Component {

  state = { hideZebraPic : false};

  onClickHandler = () => {
    this.setState( prev => ({ hideZebraPic : !prev.hideZebraPic }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={mind_zebra} onClick={this.onClickHandler} className="MindZebraPic" alt="zebra"/>
        {this.state.hideZebraPic ? <Entry /> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: model from here https://jsfiddle.net/37qztz6x/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but the below is the answer more what I need. Sorry if there was a confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are **always** rendering the image. There is no condition to not render it in your `render` function.

If I'm understanding properly what you want to achieve, the right code for the `render` function would be:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.hideZebraPic) {
    return <Dropdown />;
  } else {
    return <img src={mind_zebra} onClick={this.onClickHandler} />;
  }
}
```

It could be also written like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {!this.state.hideZebraPic && (
        <img src={mind_zebra} onClick={this.onClickHandler} />
      )}
      {this.state.hideZebraPic && <Dropdown />}
    </div>
  );
}
```